# Minimum macOS deployment target for macCatalyst project?

Tags: macos, uikitformac, mac-catalyst

Today I ported iPad project to macOS through macCatalyst. This is a simple project like dictionary between two languages. What is the minimum macOS deployment target for macCatalyst project?
Can I set lower than 10.15 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. The Catalyst runtime is only available on macOS Catalina (10.15). The runtime in Mojave (10.14) is quite different, so you cannot target that.